# Backtesting Trading Strategy with python and pandas - Recognizing only one open position at a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, trading

This is a long read but I looked through as many examples on StackOverflow of creating functions to iterate through DataFrames, etc. and just couldn't find anything to fit my needs. I have also only been using python and coding in general for about 2 months, so I apologize if something is unclear.

I have a dataframe with daily price history and am trying to create a back-test for buy signals based on this strategy:

We first look for a day where the closing price is **greater than** the closing price of **both the day before and the day after**. Let's call this the "base day."

To initiate our buy signal we wait for a day where the closing price is back above the "base day." We now have an open position.

We hold this position until we get a sell signal which comes from the opposite of what our buy signal was looking for. (ie. closing price below a previous day where day prior and day after were higher)

I only want one buy to be active at a time until we get a sell signal and then the process starts over.

Below is an example dataframe with a small portion of the data I am looking at

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'date': [1/3/2000,1/4/2000,1/5/2000,1/6/2000,1/7/2000,1/10/2000,1/11/2000,1/12/2000,1/13/2000,1/14/2000,1/18/2000,1/19/2000,1/20/2000,1/21/2000,1/24/2000,1/25/2000,1/26/2000,1/27/2000,1/28/2000,1/31/2000,2/1/2000,2/2/2000,2/3/2000,2/4/2000,2/7/2000,2/8/2000,2/9/2000,2/10/2000,2/11/2000,2/14/2000,2/15/2000,2/16/2000,2/17/2000,2/18/2000,2/22/2000,2/23/2000,2/24/2000,2/25/2000,2/28/2000,2/29/2000],

'close': [308.3,315.3,314.4,307.5,309.8,313.4,310.7,324.2,332.5,348.8,351.1,348.2,348.7,343.5,343,343.3,342.4,343,334.4,334.6,336,333.8,331.6,332.8,335.9,341.2,338.4,342.1,343.2,339.5,346.9,342,339.6,337.4,335,330.8,331.3,331.1,332.6,335.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
## Create columns to compare price to day before and day after
df['prev_close'] = df['close'].shift(1)
df['next_close'] = df['close'].shift(-1)


## BOOLEAN TO RETURN IF PRICE IS LOWER THAN PREVIOUS AND NEXT DAY
df['high_high'] = ((df['prev_close']) > df['close']) & ((df['next_close']) > df['close'])

## BOOLEAN TO RETURN TRUE IF PRICE IS GREATER THAN PREVIOUS AND NEXT DAY
df['low_low'] = ((df['prev_close']) < df['close']) & ((df['next_close']) < df['close'])


## RETURN PRICE OF MOST RECENT true IN low_low
df['comp_price'] = df['close'].where(df['low_low'] == True)
## FILL IN BLANKS WITH PREVIOUS VALUE TO KEEP COMPARISON PRICE ACTIVE
df['comp_price'].fillna(method='pad',inplace=True)

## CREATE SELL COMPARISON DATE TO REFERENCE WHEN CLOSING POSITION
df['sell_comp'] = df['close'].where(df['high_high'] == True)
df['sell_comp'].fillna(method='pad',inplace=True)

## CREATE BUY SIGNAL
df['buy_sig'] = df['close'] > df['comp_price']

## DESIGNATE FIRST INSTANCE OF BUY SIGNAL AS DAY TO OPEN POSITION
df['open_pos'] = (df['buy_sig'] == 1) & (df['buy_sig'].shift(1) != 1)
df['take_signal'] = (df['buy_sig'] == 1) & (df['open_pos'] == True)
df['open_pos_price'] = df['close'].where(df['take_signal'] == True)
df['open_pos_price'].fillna(method='pad',inplace=True)


## CREATE SELL SIGNAL
df['sell_sig'] = df['close'] < df['sell_comp']
## DESIGNATE FIRST INSTANCE OF SELL AS DAY TO CLOSE POSITION
df['close_pos'] = (df['sell_sig'] == True) & (df['sell_sig'].shift(1) == False)

## CREATE COLUMNS THAT ORGANIZE WHEN POSITION WAS OPENED
df['open_pos_date'] = df['date'].where((df['open_pos'] == True)&(df['take_signal'] == True))
df['open_pos_date'].fillna(method='pad',inplace=True)

## CREATE COLUMNS SHOW DATE AND PRICE OF CLOSING POSITION
df['close_pos_price'] = df['close'].where(df['close_pos'] == True)
df['close_pos_date'] = df['date'].where((df['close_pos'] == True))

## CALCULATE GAIN FOR TRADE
df['gain'] = (df['close_pos_price'] - df['open_pos_price']).where((df['close_pos_price'] > 0)& (df['open_pos_price'] > 0))
```

I then created another dataframe that showed the results when I got sell signals so I could later turn the results into Tuples and iterate through to add transaction cost, etc, to finish out for charting purposes.

```
strat_df = df.loc[(df['close_pos'] == True)&(df['sell_sig'] == True), ['open_pos_date','open_pos_price', 'close_pos_date','close_pos_price','gain']]
```

I see multiple instances of the same `open_pos_date` with different `close_pos_date` values. Somewhere along the way I am allowing multiple open positions to be working.

I want to hold my first buy signal as my only position, ignoring all other buy signals, until I get a sell signal. At that point I want to look for a new buy signal and hold that one position only until I get a new sell.

I've probably created way more columns than necessary, but I was having trouble finding a way to get a unique signal to take a position and then compare the price to what that price would be when I got the sell signal. If anyone can recommend a cleaner way to do this, I'd gladly scrap my first attempt and give it a try.

Comment: Please reduce this explanation and code to a [mcve], it is _extremely_ difficult to understand your problem at first glance.

Comment: Congrats on your first question. 
 Welcome to StackOverflow! https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you normally want to avoid iterating over the rows of a dataframe as it's pretty slow and inefficient, I find that it's usually the best method when backtesting.  Since your positions and portfolio values depend on T-1 values in order to calculate values at T, it's usually necessary to go row by row, and it's a lot simpler.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'date': ['1/3/2000','1/4/2000','1/5/2000','1/6/2000','1/7/2000','1/10/2000',
                '1/11/2000','1/12/2000','1/13/2000','1/14/2000','1/18/2000','1/19/2000','1/20/2000','1/21/2000',
                 '1/24/2000','1/25/2000','1/26/2000','1/27/2000','1/28/2000','1/31/2000','2/1/2000','2/2/2000',
                 '2/3/2000','2/4/2000','2/7/2000','2/8/2000','2/9/2000','2/10/2000','2/11/2000','2/14/2000',
                 '2/15/2000','2/16/2000','2/17/2000','2/18/2000','2/22/2000','2/23/2000','2/24/2000','2/25/2000',
                 '2/28/2000','2/29/2000'],
'close': [308.3,315.3,314.4,307.5,309.8,313.4,310.7,324.2,332.5,348.8,351.1,348.2,348.7,343.5,343,343.3,342.4,343,
          334.4,334.6,336,333.8,331.6,332.8,335.9,341.2,338.4,342.1,343.2,339.5,346.9,342,339.6,337.4,335,330.8,331.3,
          331.1,332.6,335.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(['date'])
df['pos'] = 0

base_buy = 999999.0
base_sell = 0.0
for i in range(2, df.shape[0] - 1):

    px_m1 = df.iloc[i - 1].loc['close']
    px = df.iloc[i].loc['close']
    px_p1 = df.iloc[i + 1].loc['close']
    pos = df.iloc[i - 1].loc['pos']

    #base_buy
    if px > px_m1 and px > px_p1 and pos == 0:
        base_buy = px

    #entry signal
    if px > base_buy and pos == 0:
        pos = 1.0
        base_sell = 0.0

    #base_sell
    if px < px_m1 and px < px_p1 and pos == 1:
        base_sell = px

    #exit signal
    if px < base_sell and pos == 1.0:
        pos = 0.0
        base_buy = 999999.0

    df.iloc[i, 1] = pos

print(df)
```

output:

```
           close  pos
date                 
1/3/2000   308.3  0.0
1/4/2000   315.3  0.0
1/5/2000   314.4  0.0
1/6/2000   307.5  0.0
1/7/2000   309.8  0.0
1/10/2000  313.4  0.0
1/11/2000  310.7  0.0
1/12/2000  324.2  1.0
1/13/2000  332.5  1.0
1/14/2000  348.8  1.0
1/18/2000  351.1  1.0
1/19/2000  348.2  1.0
1/20/2000  348.7  1.0
1/21/2000  343.5  0.0
1/24/2000  343.0  0.0
1/25/2000  343.3  0.0
```

Comment: You've boiled the problem down a lot here, which is great. But could you not just `np.roll` the column and assign it to another column? That way you have values offset by 1 index in the same row. Not sure I can test now but it might avoid the `for` loops.

Comment: I appreciate the response but the buy signal I am looking for needs to  come after we trade back above the closing price of the day your code is producing as the entry signal. Similarly, the exit signal comes after we trade below the closing price of the day you're producing the exit signal.

Comment: So, if the base day is a day when the price is below the day before and the day after, then the trade day is always the day after the base day, since by definition base day is lower than the day after it?  Am I understanding that right?

Comment: I edited the entry and exit rules as I understand them.  If that's still not right, maybe an example list of what position you're expecting on which days would help clarify.

Comment: Troy, I apologize I really botched my first question on here. The code in my first post is correct but the description prior to the code for the buy signal was backwards. I have fixed my original post. The base price would be a closing price where the day before and Day after are lower. The buy signal comes when we close back above the base price. Is that more clear? I really appreciate your help...

Comment: Ok, I added a base_buy and base_sell clause.  Maybe a little hacky but I think that now gives the right output.